# Python trouble creating a list of all divisible numbers

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, counting, iterable

I'm just trying to create a list of all numbers possible that are divisible by the number given by the user, and I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that.. I thought `itertools` would would work, but I get the error `Expected Collection.Iterable, got 'int' instead` on line 5. Really just looking for any type of solution to this problem. Thanks in advance!

```
import itertools
num = int(input('please enter a number'))
list_range = itertools.count
divisor_list = []
for number in list_range:
    if num % number == 0:
        divisor_list.append(number)
print(divisor_list)
```

also tried this without any luck:

```
num = int(input('please enter a number'))
list_range = 0, 1
divisor_list = []
while list_range < num:
    for number in list_range:
        if num % number == 0:
            divisor_list.append(number)
        list_range += 1
    print(divisor_list)
```

Comment: Not possible: too many numbers are divisible to get them all into your computers ram

Comment: The correct algorithm for that would never end, those numbers are infinite. Guess you are looking to get a list of all numbers that can divide the given number maybe?

Comment: @jtagle Yes, that is my goal, didn't know exactly how to word it

Comment: @jtagle is there any solution for that that would be possible? say the user inputs 500, i would like it to return
```
[2, 4, 10, 12, 20, 25, 50, 100, 250]
```